# How to use helm charts without internet access

Tags: docker, charts, deployment, kubernetes-helm

All of us know that `helm` charts are amazing and make our lives easier.

However, I got a use case when I would like to use `helm` charts - **WITHOUT INTERNET ACCESS**

And there are two steps:

- Downloading chart from Git
- Pulling Docker images from Dockerhub (spefified in `values.yaml` files)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

Using a helm chart offline involves pulling the chart from the internet then installing it.:

```
$ helm pull <chart name>
$ ls #The chart will be pulled as a tar to the local directory
$ helm install <whatever release name you want>  <chart name>.tgz
```

For this method to work you'll need all the docker images the chart uses locally as you mentioned.

Comment: This is useful for offline environments. Many thanks! In the offline env, obviously we do not have Internet, only have secure SSH for a few secure VMs. So I `helm pull` from a server with Internet access, `scp` to the off-grid env and then do the `helm install`.

Answer (score 3):

> Pulling docker images from Dockerhub WITHOUT INTERNET ACCESS

Obviously, that is not possible. However, the problem can be addressed by splitting it into stages:

1. Pull the docker images from Dockerhub to a system that *has* internet access.
2. Save the docker images [docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/), copy them to the destination environment where you want to do offline installation and load the images back [docker load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/)
3. Setup a docker registry in the destination environment and tag / push the docker images into this registry. [Local docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)
4. In the helm charts / kubernetes yaml files, update image references to point to the local docker registry [Kubernetes and private docker registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

Alternatively, you can look at offline packaging / deployment tools like [Gravity](https://goteleport.com/gravity/)

Answer (score 2):

I know the answer to the **first part of my question**.

you can actually `git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/charts.git` all offical charts from github and specify path to a chart (folder) on your filesystem you want to install.

This will be in form of `helmfile`

execute the command like this:

`helmfile -f deployment.yaml sync`

```
cat deployment.yaml
...
repositories:
  - name: roboll
    url: http://roboll.io/charts

context: example.int.com                # kube-context (--kube-context)

releases:

  # Prometheus deployment
  - name: my_prometheus              # name of this release
    namespace: monitoring                       # target namespace
    chart: /opt/heml/charts/stable/prometheus                    # the chart being installed to create this release, referenced by `repository/chart` syntax
    values: ["values/values_prometheus_ns_monitoring.yaml"]
    set:                                        # values (--set)
      - name: rbac.create
        value: true
  # Grafana deployment
  - name: my_grafana              # name of this release
    namespace: monitoring                       # target namespace
    chart: /opt/heml/charts/stable/grafana
    values: ["values/values_grafana_ns_monitoring.yaml"]
```

So as you can see I have specified some custom `values_<software>_ns_monitoring.yaml` files.

The second part of my original question is still **unanswered**.

I want to be able to tell `docker` to use a local **docker image in this section**

```
cat values_grafana_ns_monitoring.yaml

replicas: 1

image:
  repository: grafana/grafana
  tag: 5.0.4
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

I have managed to manually **copy/paste** - then **load docker image**
so it is visible in my computer - but I can't figure out how to convince 
**docker + helmfile** to use my image. The goal is to process totally **offlilne** installation.

ANY IDEAS ???

```
 sudo docker images
[sudo] password for jantoth:
REPOSITORY                                                       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
my_made_up_string/custom_grafana/custom_grafana                               5.1.2               917f46a60761        6 days ago          238 MB
```